# Why is this recursive call for backward chaining flawed?

Tags: logic, algorithms

I'm studying [backwards chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_chaining) for an exam in AI and I understand the overall idea. However, I'm confused about the following slides from one of the lectures:

---

[image]

[image]

---

where $KB = \text{knowledge base}$.

> My question: why is this version flawed? I get that in the flawed version when determining the rule $P \text{ if } Q_1$ we return something no matter what, but I don't see why its wrong to do that in this specific case. What am I missing?

Note: I didn't really know where to ask this question, so please feel free to guide me to another site if the question isn't relevant in this forum. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens in the second version if there is no rule whose head is $P$?

Comment: What happens if there are two rules that can prove the goal, the first of which has as premise which can't be proven, but the second of which has premises which can be proven?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Then I guess we wouldn't return anything, which of course doesn't work. But would it then be sufficient to add a "RETURN failure;" at the very end?

Comment: @Mjiig But is that a problem in this case? If $Q_1$ isn't a succes then the following rule ($Q_1$ and $Q_2$) isn't a succes either.

Comment: Consider the following knowledge base: "I'm happy if I read a good book," and "I'm happy if the sun shines."

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I see that then we would return failure if I didn't read a good book, but it could be that the sun is shining and therefore I am happy, thus it would be wrong to return failure before checking if the sun is shining. However, as I see it, the KB in this case would be "I'm happy if I read a good book" and "I'm happy if I read a good book and the sun is shining". I guess the problem lies in the fact that I'm very dependent on the order in which the rules are checked?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how case statements works. Those 3 literal statements aren't the contents of the knowledgebase, they're placeholders against which statements in the knowledgebase get matched. Specifically $Q_1$ can mean totally different things on the fifth and sixth lines.

Comment: @Mjiig If that is the case I see why it becomes af problem. I will have to read up on it. Thank you for your time (both of you).

Answer (score 1):

When solving a subgoal returns a failure, the second algorithm returns failure, while the first algorithm tries to find another applicable rule in the knowledge base. So the second algorithm can get stuck in a blind alley.